# Как отредактировать код для корректной отправки данных сайта в битрикс 24?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, битрикс24

нужна помощь, создает лид по клику, но не отправляются данные с названием и метками. Сайт на WordPress, js-ку подключил в функшн.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Отслеживание кликов по телефонной ссылке
$('a[href^="tel:"]').click(function() {
    var utmParams = getUTMParams(); // Функция для получения utm-меток
    sendLeadToBitrix(utmParams); // Функция для отправки данных в Битрикс24
});

// Отслеживание кликов по ссылке WhatsApp
$('a[href^="https://wa.me/-------"]').click(function() {
    var utmParams = getUTMParams(); // Функция для получения utm-меток
    sendLeadToBitrix(utmParams); // Функция для отправки данных в Битрикс24
});

// Функция для получения utm-меток из URL
function getUTMParams() {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var utmParams = {};

    if (urlParams.has('utm_source')) {
        utmParams.source = urlParams.get('utm_source');
    }

    if (urlParams.has('utm_medium')) {
        utmParams.medium = urlParams.get('utm_medium');
    }

    if (urlParams.has('utm_campaign')) {
        utmParams.campaign = urlParams.get('utm_campaign');
    }

    // Дополнительные utm-метки, если нужно

    return utmParams;
}

// Функция для отправки данных в Битрикс24
function sendLeadToBitrix(utmParams) {
  var apiUrl = 'https://------.bitrix24.ru/rest/--------/-----------/crm.lead.add.json'; // Замените на фактический URL и REST API-эндпоинт
  
  var fields = {
        title: 'Новый лид 777',
        source_id: utmParams.source,
        medium_id: utmParams.medium,
        campaign_id: utmParams.campaign,

        // Дополнительные поля лидов, если нужно
    };

    // Отправка запроса на создание лида в Битрикс24
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: fields,
        params: 'REGISTER_SONET_EVENT',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Lead created successfully');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Error creating lead:', error);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в var fields не хватает переменных с WordPress тоесть

Переменная Битрикса = 'Переменная WordPress',

Поэтому лид пустой и формируется

Только учти что TITLE - это обязательное поле для создания лида (Название лида)